# Can I digitally sign JScript (.js) or VBScript (.vbs) files?

Tags: windows, vbscript, digital-signature, jscript, wsh

I know that one can sign a Windows `binary` executable file using [signtool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387764(v=vs.85).aspx). So all this time I was under assumption that one cannot sign any of the files interpreted by `Windows Script Host`, such as JScript (.js) or VBScript (.vbs) because those are mere text files.

But today, while opening a `.js` file that I downloaded off my web site, I was greeted by this warning:

[image]

So does this mean that there's a way to sign those `.js`/`.vbs` files? If so, then how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to finalize my original question. The answer is **yes**. To the best of my knowledge, one can sign the following files using Microsoft's [SignTool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz(v=vs.110).aspx):

- Obviously Windows executables: `.exe`, `.dll`, `.com` (for old DOS format), `.scr` (for screensaver), `.ocx` (for ActiveX control), `.cpl` (for Control Panel executable.)
- Windows installer files: `.msi`, `.msp`
- Text-based scripts: `.js` (for JScript), `.vbs` (for VBScript), `.jse` (for encoded JScript), `.vbe` (for encoded VBScript)
- PowerShell scripts: `.ps1` , `.psm1`, `.ps1xml`
- [Windows Script Files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_File): `.wsf` (with mixed content)

Comment: You can add `.wsf` (Windows Script File) to the list.

Comment: Can you sign HTA files? The question has come up - [Is it possible to add digital signature on a hta file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65701712).

Answer (score 2):

The [`Scripting.Signer` Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4k76xzfe%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) can sign a script with a digital signature.

```
Dim filespec : Set filespec = "my_script.vbs"
Dim cert : Set cert = "my" ' the default private certificate
Dim oSign : Set oSign = CreateObject("Scripting.Signer")
Dim fso : Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim file : Set file = fso.GetFile(filespec)

oSign.SignFile file.Path, cert
```

Comment: Hmm. That's interesting... except that I can't make it to work. I replaced `cert` in your example with the name that I get for my code signing cert that I use to sign .exe files. To get that name I run `certmgr.msc` and locate the cert in `Truster Publishers->Certificates` and get it from the `Issued To` column. But in that case the `SignFile` method returns `Error: Cannot find the certificate and private key to use for decryption.` and `Code: 8009200C`. Any idea why?

Comment: Oh, just realized that `signtool` can sign the following script files as well: `.vbs, .vbe, .js, .jse, .wsf` by adding a signature in the comments at the end. So there's no need to do this VB masturbation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz(v=vs.110).aspx It would help if that MSDN page mentioned it though...

Comment: Hmm… You might also need to pass a `store` in the third position of the `SignFile` procedure? I think `signtool` and `Scripting.Signer` might both be calling the same Windows API under the covers, anyway.